# Accessing an object from different class

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying to define and declare an class (ReorderInfo_DK) which needs reference to another old object  (MrProt &rMrProt) from my main code "“FlashBack.cpp”". However, I do not exactly know how to transfer object from main file to header file and hence, I am getting errors which I could not fix:

z:\n4\pkg\mrservers\mrimaging\seq\cestipat\ReorderInfo_DK.h(11) : error C2071: 'ReorderInfo_DK::rMrProt' : illegal storage class
z:\n4\pkg\mrservers\mrimaging\seq\cestipat\ReorderInfo_DK.h(22) : error C2758: 'ReorderInfo_DK::rMrProt' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

**Inside “ReorderInfo_DK.h” :**

```
# include "MrServers/MrProtSrv/MrProt/prot.h"

class ReorderInfo_DK {
    extern MrProt &rMrProt;
    long lREOIndex;
  public:
    ReorderInfo_DK ();
    ~ReorderInfo_DK ();

    long getLinNo (long lREOIndex);
};



ReorderInfo_DK::ReorderInfo_DK(){
    lREOIndex = 0;
}


ReorderInfo_DK::~ReorderInfo_DK(){

}
```

**Inside main code
There is a forward declaration in “FlashBack.h”**

```
//  Forward declarations                                                       
class MrProt;
```

**And then, all function inside the main code uses “MrProt &rMrProt” as an argument such as:**

```
NLSStatus FlashBack::prepare (MrProt &rMrProt, SeqLim &rSeqLim, SeqExpo &rSeqExpo)
{
………..
}
```

**I am planning to call object from my class “ReorderInfo_DK” right in this function "prepare".**

I would appreciate any help.

Regards,
Dushyant

Comment: Well yeah, what’s the `extern` doing in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MrProt` (the variable) is a global variable somewhere, then you need to put the `extern` declaration *outside* the class, or it will be considered a part of the class `ReorderInfo_DK`.

If it's not a global variable, you first need to drop the `extern` keyword to declare it as a member variable in the class, and then to pass the actual instance to the `ReorderInfo_DK` constructor, and assign it in the constructor initializer list:

```
class ReorderInfo_DK
{
    MrProt& MrProt;

public:
    ReorderInfo_DK(MrProt& mrprot)
        : MrProt(mrprot)
     {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

MrProt is a global variable and hence, I implemented your suggestion regarding putting extern declaration outside the class.

Comment: I have another question though: 
IF MrProt were NOT a global variable and I use the method as you suggested and instantiate 
 it inside this function:
NLSStatus FlashBack::prepare (MrProt &rMrProt, SeqLim &rSeqLim, SeqExpo &rSeqExpo)
{
………..
}

Do I still need to include header file, that have defintion of MrProt, in “ReorderInfo_DK.h” .
Also, I would have to initialize my object “ReorderInfo_DK_Obj” as follow:
ReorderInfo_DK ReorderInfo_DK_Obj(mrprot)

Am I right here?

Comment: @DushyantKumar In the header file where you declare the `MrProt` reference variable, then you only need a declaration of the `MrProt` class. You need the full definition for when you use the `MrProt` member. And yes that `ReorderInfo_DK_Obj` declaration is correct.